# GeoServer map layers/tiles Loaded in the screen or Not

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, web-mapping, ext-js

I'm using OpenLayers - 2.11,GeoServer 2.13, ExtJS 3.4, and Java for developing GIS based web applications.
Please guide me to check if all my GeoServer map layers/tiles Loaded in the screen or not.
While dragging map is taking time to load next tiles. So that time i want to mask all the map body and unmask after loading all the map tiles.

[image]

Comment: Are you debugging using Firebug? The Net tab and the Script Tab are most used for debugging these kinds of apps.

Comment: Dear Devdatta Tengshe,thank you for your response. i'm using Firebug here.But, how we can find out that through coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openlayers.org/dev/examples/layerLoadMonitoring.html
[Example for Openlayers map layer events..](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/layerLoadMonitoring.html)

Comment: The URL gets a blank page!!!

Comment: opening here..just click on that blue link. and check the source code

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the Layer's `loadend` event like this:

```
layer.events.register("loadend", layer, function (e) {
                //<<---Do your process here
            });
```

Comment: Dear Devdatta Tengshe..thank you.. i'm using different layer groups/layers in my map.Is there any method to check for all the layers? or All map area is loaded or not?

Comment: @RamRamesh: There is no event that fires when all layers are loaded. You need to listen to individual layer load events and then use somw custom logic to figure out if all layers are loaded.

Comment: openlayers.org/dev/examples/layerLoadMonitoring.html  example..